# regex error preg_replace_callback() : Unknown modifier '.' in

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-replace-callback

I got the following string:

```
last_name, first_name
bjorge, philip
kardashian, [kghim]
mer#$##Code:menu:51587daa7030e##$#cury some more
data #$##Code:menu:515r4387daa7dsf030e##$#, freddie
```

im trying to replace the Codes in the middle with the function: 'codeParser' the regex is:

```
$PC_File = preg_replace_callback("(?=\#\$\#\#).*?(?<=\#\#\$\#)", 'codeParser', $PC_File);
```

but getting this error:

```
PHP Warning:  preg_replace_callback() : Unknown modifier '.'
```

Comment: @Ashish I'm glad that's only a comment and not an answer :P

Comment: Now that the delimiter problem has been solved, let's talk about those lookarounds.  `'/#\$##(.*?)##\$#/'` matches the same things your regex does, but much more efficiently.  The capturing group allows you to access the `Code` value directly (via `$matches[1]`), so you don't have to strip off the surrounding stuff in a separate step.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to wrap your regular expression in [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).  It's considering `()` to be the delimiters right now, and the `.` as a modifier (which is of course invalid).

```
"/(?=#\\$##).*?(?<=##\\$#)/"
```

(I'm also pretty sure the `#` do not need to be escaped unless you were using them as delimiters)

EDIT: You need `\\` to properly escape the `$` in double-quotes.

Comment: The error is gone but still it is not calling the function, in an online regex its working, maybe preg_replace_callback isnt good for php 4.39?

Comment: Additional explanation: you can use `(` as start delimiter but then the end delimiter needs to be `)`. If you do so, the expression is just `(?=#\$##)` and `.*?(?<=##\$#)` become the flags/modifiers. Thus the error.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario correct, and I think you can also use `[]` and `{}` for delimiters in the same way.

Comment: @user1725378 what does `preg_last_error` say?

Comment: i put: file_put_contents("getFilelog.txt","error:".preg_last_error()."\n" ,FILE_APPEND); after the regex.. file say error:0

Comment: 100%! its a copy paste.

Comment: because in online regex its working, you think maybe my server dont support something here? or i got a mistake here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27338/discussion-between-user1725378-and-explosion-pills)